# How to prevent to open external link in browser in cordova?

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I am using angular2 with cordova for android app. In this I'm using payment gateway so, to do this I need to post form values to external payment URL without opening browser.

Sample code is:

```
<form action="<External URL>" method="POST">
      <input type="text" value="paymentID">
</form>
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: I improved your question so another user can easily understand.

Answer (score 1):

To make the form submit not open in browser you have to allow navigation to that url. 
You can do it by adding an `allow-navigation` entry in your config.xml like this `<allow-navigation href="http://example.com/*" />`.

In Android you will also need to install `cordova-plugin-whitelist`

But you should not really do a form submit to an external url, you should use XHR (AJAX) to send the POST to the server instead of the form submit.