# PhoneGap opens link on application not in browser

Tags: javascript, html, apache, cordova, phonegap

I'am working with phonegap and I'am ecountering the problem that when I press the submit button from the user input it keeps opening the mobile browser, all i want is to open the website through the app not by opening the mobile browser, is there any way to resolve this issue?

Script:

```
function displayCam()
{


    if (document.getElementById('ipadd').value.match(/^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/)) {
    var ip = document.getElementById('ipadd');
    var portz = document.getElementById('portz');
    //document.getElementById('camView').innerHTML = ip.value;
    var link = document.getElementById('camView').href="http://"+ip.value+":"+portz.value;
    window.location.href =link;  
    return(true);
    }
    else{
        alert("You have entered an invalid IP address or Something is missing!")  

        document.getElementById('ipadd').value = "";
        document.getElementById('portz').value = "";
        return (false);
}
```

Code:

```
<center>
         <br>
        <br>
            <h2>Please Enter IP Address</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>   

                    <th><label for="ipadd">Enter IP Address:</label></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text"  id= 'ipadd' placeholder="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" pattern="\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}" required" ></td>
                </tr>   
                <tr>    
                    <th><label for="portz">Enter Port:</label></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type='number' id='portz' pattern=".{1.4}" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th><input type='button' onclick=' displayCam() ' value='Submit' required="required"></th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="camView"> </div>

     </center>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phonegap - How to open external link inside the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737582/phonegap-how-to-open-external-link-inside-the-app)

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52478727/how-to-prevent-to-open-external-link-in-browser-in-cordova/52488470#52488470